# UI Testing - Jetpack Compose - Hilt

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

*Edit* I still need help with this ActivityNotFound error. Am I missing something from my manifest file? How would I do that? Do I need to declare my HiltTestRunner somewhere? I am so lost at this point lol. Please help.

I am trying to learn how to test with Jetpack Compose and I'm feeling lost. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I want to test the MainScreen, but it is nested in a ScreenNavigation() and needs a ViewModel and a NavController. I'm really confused how this works. It is telling me it can't find the activity. Im not sure what to do in the AndroidManifest file. Any help is very much appreciated!

Error: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.samm.brewerysearch.test/androidx.test.core.app.InstrumentationActivityInvoker$BootstrapActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>


<application
    android:name="com.samm.brewerysearch.BrewApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Bloomberg"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name="com.samm.brewerysearch.MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Bloomberg">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

```
@HiltAndroidTest
@UninstallModules(AppModule::class)
class MainScreenTest {

    @get:Rule(order = 0)
    val hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    @get:Rule(order = 1)
    val composeRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        hiltRule.inject()

        composeRule.setContent {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            
            BreweryTheme {
                NavHost(
                    navController = navController,
                    startDestination = Screens.MainScreen.name
                ){
                    composable(Screens.MainScreen.name){
                        MainScreen(
                            navController = navController,
                            mainViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
                            search = Constants.DEFAULT_CITY
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Test
    fun myTest(){
        composeRule.onNodeWithText(Constants.DEFAULT_CITY).assertIsDisplayed()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using composeTestRule.activity.apply{} worked!

```
   composeTestRule.activity.apply {
       setContent { ... }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these rule to test your screen and mock viremodel

```
  @get:Rule
     val initRule: MockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule() 

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<ComponentActivity>()
    
    @Mock
    lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
```

you can initialize your navcontroller by

```
this.navController  = rememberNavController()
```

furthermore ther's no need to add `@HiltAndroidTest` annotation to your class, replace this annotation with `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)`

here's complete code of screen test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class PCListScreenTest {


    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<ComponentActivity>()

    @get:Rule
    val initRule: MockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()

    @Mock
    lateinit var abcSharedViewModel: AbcSharedViewModel

    @Mock
    lateinit var pcViewModel: PcViewModel

    @Mock
    lateinit var carViewModel: CarViewModel


    fun setup() {
      
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            PCListScreen(
                navController = rememberNavController(),
                pcViewModel = pcViewModel,
                abcSharedViewModel = abcSharedViewModel,
                category = listOf(),
                carViewModel = carViewModel
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: still throwing the same error. I guess I am missing something in the manifest file? thank you for the reply!

Comment: please add below dependencies in your build.gradle file
        testImplementation: 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.4.0',
             'org.mockito:mockito-inline:3.4.0',
             "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3",
             'com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.2.0',
             'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.3.4',
             'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:2.9.0',
             'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.3'

Comment: mockito is throwing even more errors. if i'm using hilt, shouldn't I have to use a @HiltAndroidTest? this is so confusing.

Comment: no you shouldn't, use only this annotation
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)

Comment: I've edit my answer and gave you complete code of screen test

Comment: I ended up not being able to use Mockito but thank you for the help.